# Algebra & rearranging equations (economics context) help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Q: $$PxX+PyY = I$$

Px means price of X, which is **1**. Py means price of Y, which is **2**. I means income, which is **60**.

Therefore, it's $$1X + 2Y = 60$$

X is 15, and Y is 22.5 when you solve them.

However, now there is a tax imposed on each Y unit (£), so the price of Y increases and now we can buy less Y (so, Y won't be 22.5 anymore). Income and the value for X stay the same.

So, I imagine the equation now looks like: $$1X+2Y£ = 60$$

Question: what's the value of £ if the government wants to receive £20?

**Edit**: I think I've found it. $$1(15) + 3.6(12.5) = 60$$ and 1.6 multiplied by 12.5 is £20, i.e. the amount the govt. gets. However, I literally kept plugging in values to get this until it worked. I don't know how to solve it more easily. Does anyone know?

Comment: How do you get x=15 and y=22.5?  There are many solutions to the equation for two unknowns eg X=10 Y=25

Comment: It's related to a concept in economics called utility maximisation, so those values satisfy an earlier assumption. However, it's not relevant here. I basically need to know what values of Y & £ multiply together to get £20 (since the government gets £20), but that also satisfies the equation $$IX + 2Y£ = 60$$ when you plug in the values, which I'm not sure how to do here. Essentially, the tax (£) increases the price of Y, which means you can no longer afford 22.5 units.

Comment: where did you get 1.6 at the bottom?

Comment: It was originally 2Y. The tax (£) is essentially an increase in the price, 2. Increasing 2 to 3.6 means that 15 + 3.6(12.5) = 60, and 1.6 (3.6 - 2) multiplied by the new value of Y (12.5 units) is 20, i.e. the amount of tax rev the govt. gets.

Comment: I am having a little trouble understanding your question, tell me if my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So you wanted to solve $$15+xy=60\implies xy=45\\(x-2)y=20\implies xy=20+2y$$

You can see the $xy$ term in both equations, so $$20+2y=45\implies y=\frac{25}{2}=12.5$$

Plugging in the values and solving for $x$ gives you the $x$ and $y$ values. That is the method not trial and error.